# Factoring in SEO on a Flash Site

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, flash, seo

There have been many debates about this topic already here, but none of them fully answered my question so I figured I would pose it and hope I get one or two decent answers.

We're planning on relaunching our company website in the next few months. Our current site, for the most part, is text-driven and because of this we rank very well on Google, Yahoo, and Bing for our primary keywords.  We want to increase the "Wow Factor" of the site a bit (we're an interactive agency) but still maintain a majority of our search engine footing.  The option to use Flash, AJAX, and other technologies that are not considered to be search engine friendly have come up numerous times in our meetings and each time we have to evaluate what kind of impact it would have on us from an SEO perspective.

Assuming a good portion of the site content will be encapsulated within a Flash (swf) file, what would be the best course of action for maintaining current rankings?  I've read numerous times that Google indexes Flash files but I am unsure as to what extent.  Further, is there a method of telling Google *not* to index a Flash file (through a variable or otherwise)?

Finally, I had an idea that seemed sound in theory and wanted to put it out into the world and see what type of feedback I receive on it:

Again, assuming the whole page is in a Flash file living on index.html, would it be possible to build out the site as normal (set up a logical directory structure, add content to static pages within said structure, etc), specify paths to those static pages in a Google XML Sitemap file, and have the spiders crawl only those pages (which are rich in content) while the user experiences some concoction of Flash/Javascript/AJAX/etc?  If this works, what would be the pros/cons of this solution?  Thanks for bearing with me on this slightly off-kilter question.

Comment: What experience do you want non-flash users to have?

Comment: Non Flash users would be greeted with some type of alternative content, like what the swfobject Javascript provides.  We're in the early conceptual stages of this project, so all of the details haven't fully been hashed out yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well referencing [Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html) I found that they have made impressive strides into indexing Flash based web pages.  The only limitation I found from reading the article is that they are currently still limited in their ability in these three areas:

> 1. Googlebot does not execute some types of JavaScript. So if your web
>    page loads a Flash file via
>    JavaScript, Google may not be aware of
>    that Flash file, in which case it will
>    not be indexed.
> 2. We currently do not attach content from external resources that are
>    loaded by your Flash files. If your
>    Flash file loads an HTML file, an XML
>    file, another SWF file, etc., Google
>    will separately index that resource,
>    but it will not yet be considered to
>    be part of the content in your Flash
>    file.
> 3. While we are able to index Flash in almost all of the languages found on
>    the web, currently there are
>    difficulties with Flash content
>    written in bidirectional languages.
>    Until this is fixed, we will be unable
>    to index Hebrew language or Arabic
>    language content from Flash files.

By the sounds of it you won't have any problems with any of the 3 'problems'.  Based on this document Flash sounds like a viable option for you.

[Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swf_searchability.html) has been working on their end as well to accommodate the search engines in their stride to make SWFs more search engine friendly as well.  So with the combined efforts of both Adobe and Google/Yahoo if you take a dip in ranking within a year or two the search algorithms will be better than they are even now.

As far as not indexing you should be able to add in a simple

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory/
Disallow: /directory/page.html
```

to your robots.txt file.

Comment: How would this indexed content appear on Google?  For instance, say Google indexes the "About Us" page, which would require navigating through the Flash.  Would the link that Google provides simply send the user to index.html where the Flash lives?  Also, what about Bing and Yahoo?  Obviously Google is the big fish in terms of search, but does Bing (and ergo) Yahoo have the capabilities to index Flash files?

Comment: Anyone who knows more can correct me if this is wrong but, a website that is composed of 1 swf file will probably be indexed completely.  That is where the problem would lie though.  Being indexed completely means search terms that would bring up the 'About Us' page would inevitably link straight to the homepage.  I believe and am not positive if you can use something such as Flex to gear a URL to a certain point in a timeline of flash?  So if you made separate swf files for each page with a different URL for each then I would say it could accurately index that as opposed to 1 large site swf.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew,

I've had to deal with this sort of thing a few times and I'd recommend maintaining both a Flash site (for users) and an HTML site (for search engines).  Here's how you do it:

- With whatever server-side stuff you're using set up some kind of switch that determines whether a particular request is for HTML or for whatever your Flash movie consumes (XML, JSON, another SWF, whatever).  **Every page** on your site should be able to return HTML **and** whatever you choose to feed your Flash movie.  A query string parameter like "requestType=Flash" will work just fine.
- Put all of the content in your HTML pages in a div tag and make the div invisible with CSS.  Use **SWFObject** to check if the requesting browser supports Flash and, if it does, have SWFObject replace your HTML content with your Flash movie.  Search engine spiders will ignore your scripts and simply crawl your HTML pages and if you'd like to show the HTML to users with browsers that don't support Flash (like mobile browsers), just make the HTML content visible after SWFObject has determined that the browser doesn't support Flash.
- Once your Flash movie has loaded, have it request whatever data it needs from the server using the **same URL** of the page that it was loaded on, but with the addition of the switch variable above.
- Handle navigation from that point on with **SWFAddress**.  When a user clicks a button to request a new page, pass the request through SWFAddress first, which will update the browser history using the hash mark trick, and then have your Flash movie make its request to the server.

I'm currently working on a site for a friend that uses this technique here (I should note, to protect my pride, that the site is still very much a work in progress):

http://www.casabarbuenosaires.com/

A browser request to any page on the site will first return the HTML representation of that page (you can view source in your browser to see that).  SWFObject then replaces the HTML content with a Flash movie that loads a custom XML description of the same page which the Flash movie then constructs and displays.

I've worked on sites in the past that have used this technique and gotten excellent search engine results.  Since you don't need to worry too much about what your HTML site looks like to humans, you can focus solely on what it looks like to search engines.

Another added benefit of building your site this way is that you are compelled to separate your site's content/copy from its visual representation.  Throwing your entire site into a single SWF is generally NOT a good way to do that.  It's much easier to maintain (or re-skin or scrap) a site when your content isn't all mixed up with your code.

Hope this helps,

Scott

Comment: Wow, that was a great help, Scott.  I think we'll really be on to something after experimenting a bit with the combinations of solutions you've offered.

Comment: Also keep in mind that not everyone has Flash installed or Flash enabled. When I view casabarbuenosaires.com all I get is a blank browser.